# Do I have to null check every time before referencing an element in view binding?

Tags: android, null, null-check, viewbinding

So this isn't really a issue, I am just curious, do I really have to null check every time I use view binding? I find it a bit annoying having to put the question mark every time (binding?.[layout item]).

Can somebody please give me a solution to this if it's possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only reason you would be doing this is if you had marked the `Binding` object as nullable, e.g. `lateinit var binding MainActivityBinding?`. Which there is no need for.

Comment: Oh yes, thanks! I totally forgot that every time I'm making the binding I am making it a nullable. I'm doing an android course and in the course the instructor does it that way, I guess I'll use the binding without making a nullable.